# AS2 code to AS3 - Percent calculator

Tags: actionscript-3

```
this.onenterframe = function () {
  var _local2 = percent.text * of.text;
  var _local1 = _local2 / number(100);
  if (of.text === "") {
    answer.text = "";
  }
  else if (of.text > "0") {
    answer.text = _local1;
  }
};
```

I used this code years back and now I want to how to get to work again in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

AS3 uses events, so the way you would rewrite this code is:

In my example, I am adding the event lister to `stage`, but in your code, you may need to add it elsewhere depending on what you're doing.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame($e:Event):void
{
    var _local2:Number = Number(percent.text) * Number(of.text);
    var _local1:Number = _local2 / 100;
    if (of.text === "") 
    {
        answer.text = "";
    }
    else if (Number(of.text) > 0) 
    {
        answer.text = _local1;
    }
}
```